# How can I wrap my user control in code behind?

Tags: c#, user-controls, code-behind

In my jquery I do:

```
var userControl = $('#userControl').wrap('<li />').parent()
```

how can I do that on the server? So far I have:

```
UserControl userControl = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/userControl.ascx");
Content.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a PlaceHolder. A PlaceHolder does not load a container element. Assume that the Placeholder is called plcTest:

```
 UserControl userControl = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/userControl.ascx");
 plcTest.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

Frontend code would look like this:

```
<li><asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcTest" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
UserControl userControl = Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/userControl.ascx");
li.Controls.Add(userControl);
Content.Controls.Add(li);
```